# Airbus A320 Business class seats power

Tags: airbus, seats

I have acquired a pair of old business class seats taken from an Airbus A320.
They have old 4:3 individual screens and power reclining and massage chairs. Wonder if anyone could guide me to powering them up with some schemes and power needs/specs to make them running.

As for the moment I’ve been using them with manual reclining (each seat has 2 knobs that release the hidraulics for the back reclining and foot rest) but would like to fully use them with electrical reclining.

Thank you

Comment: Where did you acquire the seats? Whoever sold or gave them to you might have a wiring diagram or something else that could help?

Comment: Can you find a manufacturer or supplier name / number on the seats?  Most transport aircraft interior components are supplied by subcontractors -- different airlines will customize the interior just the way they want.  The seats are not likely to be made by Airbus.

Comment: @RobMcDonald, Agreed, Zodiac is possibly the provider, acquired by Safran.

Comment: You'd need documentation or to open it up and do some basic reverse engineering of the motors - be aware there is a reasonable probability that the motors are 400hz, which will run badly or even catch fire connected to 50/60hz domestic power so do the homework before 'just plugging them in'

Comment: I would speculate that the seats do not include the computer required to make the screen work the way it did on the airplane.  Also, I am nearly certain the seats do not include hydraulics.